# SQL - join 2 tables but return all if 1 table empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

Using CodeIgniter Active Records:

```
    $country = $_SESSION['search'];
    $min_price = $_SESSION['min_price'];
    $max_price = $_SESSION['max_price'];
    $condition = "";
    $this->db->select('*,attachments.title as image');
    $this->db->from('details');
    $this->db->join('attachments', 'attachments.parent = details.id');
    $this->db->where('attachments.type', 'quotes');
    if ($country != '')
        {
        $condition .= "(details.service_location IN ('" . $country . "') OR details.country in ('" . $country . "'))";

        $this->db->where($condition);
        }

        $this->db->where('details.price_range_from >=', $min_price);
        $this->db->where('details.price_range_to <=', $max_price);


    $this->db->group_by("attachments.parent");
    $this->db->order_by("details.created_on", "asc");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;
    }
```

I have 2 tables say details and attachments, and I want to do a join on them.

Table details will always have records in it.

When table attachments has rows in it, I want the query to turn all the rows in which table details and table attachments matches. (i.e. behave like inner join)

However, if table attachments  is empty, I'd like to return everything from table details.

and also checking table attachments in where condition.

Is this possible to do in 1 query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LEFT OUTER JOIN rather than JOIN

```
FROM (details) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN attachments ON attachments.parent = details.restaurant_id
```

UPDATE

and of course

```
GROUP BY details.restaurant_id
```

rather than `attachments.parent`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but its not working. still no result
where condition also checking table attachment "$this->db->where('attachments.type', 'quotes');"

Comment: Why did you remove original query?

Answer (score 0):

Although I think it's a bit weird requirement, the principal structure you can use is:

`inner join
union
select *, ... from details where 0 = (select count(*) from attachments where ...)`

If the inner join doesn't return rows, the second query will return all details.
If the inner join returns rows, the second query won't return anything because attachments are found (count(*) returns some positive value).

I think you can fill in the details yourself.
I don't guarantee for brilliant performance.

Answer (score 0):

Use two different queries, check if attachments has rows and run query with  inner join details else return rows from details table

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @attachments where column1='')
   BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM attachments as atc 
  INNER JOIN details AS det ON   atc.parent = det.restaurant_id where column2=''
END
ELSE
  SELECT * FROM details  where column2=''
```